# How do I use a local tree-sitter grammar in my emacs major mode?

Tags: major-mode, tree-sitter

I want to create a new major mode for a language with tree-sitter. I am working on the tree-sitter parser locally and It's working (tested in neovim and helix)

Now I want to tell emacs to use the grammar to do syntax highlighting and eventually use in text objects.

How do I do that?
Here is the current major mode code

```
(define-derived-mode imba-mode fundamental-mode "imba"
  "major mode for editing imba language code."
  (add-hook 'imba-mode-hook #'tree-sitter-hl-mode))
```